# i set my array now i have to get the entire array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, getter-setter

Ok so i have a program where it sets an array with values and then asks for them at a later time as programs do.

```
int[] foo = new int[10]; //init array 
//also added a getter and setter for this array 

setFoo(fooLocal); //setter being implemented
```

now in another part of my code i want to access these values using a for loop but it seems like this won't really work because you really don't have a place to put the value from the for loop.

```
for (x = 0; x < getFoo().length; x++){
    //this is where i get a bit confused 
    getFoo(x); //im not really sure what to do here?
}
```

this answer is probably very simple but i haven't come across anything like it yet. please help or reference would be great thank you :)

Comment: Could you add the method headers of `getFoo(..)` and `setFoo(..)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming getFoo() returns an the array `foo` (which seems to be the case from your for loop statement), you can access index `x` of `foo` with:

```
int a = getFoo()[x];
```

From there, you can use `a` as you would any other int.

This is slightly inefficient though, especially if `getFoo()` has to do computation of any kind. A slightly more efficient way to do this is to grab a reference to `foo` before starting the for loop:

```
int[] foo = getFoo();
for(int x = 0; x < foo.length; x++){
    int a = foo[x];
    //do stuff with a
}
```

Even more concisely, you can use a for-each loop to simply get each element of `foo` in turn without worrying about indices. This approach becomes less enticing if you do need the index value, however.

```
for(int a : getFoo()){
    //do stuff with a
}
```

Comment: YES YES YES!!! I knew it was something so simple thanks so much!!!! I thought that this would give me an error for some reason

Comment: No problem! It can look a bit weird at first glance, but when you break down what each part is doing it makes sense. Upvotes/accept appreciated.

Comment: Note here it would be better to call `getFoo` once and store result in array instead of calling method in loop.

Comment: True. I'll add some other options to my answer. I would note that the ability to access a value at a given index from an array returned from a method (man what a mouthful) is useful, and the `getFoo()[x]` notation is weird to say the least.

Comment: i would love to upvote but i am too new to stack i dont have the rep

Comment: Or, Arrays.toString(getFoo()) which is more concise yet.